# SQL Query which returns set of tuples that exists for a given data range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table say EmployeeAbsence that has three columns: EmployeeId, LeaveReason and Date. This table records attendance of employees on a daily basis. I want to know the list of employees who took leave in last 14 days.

For example,

```
1 XYZ 2009-07-20
2 XYZ 2009-07-19
--
---
--
1001 XYZ 2009-07-04
```

In this case, my query output should return XYZ and alike because it contains entries for employees who were absent for last 14 days consecutively. I would appreciate an ORACLE query.

Comment: What is exact meaning of Date column? Is it the beginning date of absence? Or is there a record for every day that the employee was absent? And how many rows do you want to retrieve for employees that took leave 3 times for 3 different reasons during last 14 days?

Answer (score 1):

Your query will need two constraints

1. Data of leave must be less than 14 days away from current date
2. Employee has to appear only once if they have been on leave for several days / times during the 14 day period

For constraint (1) you need to know that subtracting date A from date B results in the number of days between those two dates.

For constraint (2) you need to group by the employees ID.

That said

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM EmployeeAbsence
WHERE Date between SYSDATE - 14 and SYSDATE
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that table has 1 record for each day of absence and you don't want to retrieve employees that were absent for e.g. last month but returned during last 14 days.

```
SELECT employeeId
FROM employeeAbsences base
WHERE date > trunc(sysdate)-15 -- we want to include one more day for HAVING clause to work with 
GROUP BY employeeId
-- had 2 or more non-consecutive leaves --> at least one of them started during last 14 days
HAVING count(*) < max(date) - min(date) 
   -- first absence is less than 14 days ago
   OR min(date) > trunc(sysdate) - 14;
```